# Azure ARM: deploymentScripts and first-party app identity error

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I try to execute the current ARM template for Storage static website fonctionnality activation :

```json
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",
            "apiVersion": "2019-10-01-preview",
            "name": "[variables('scriptName')]",
            "location": "[variables('regionName')]",
            // "kind": "AzurePowerShell",
            "kind": "AzureCLI",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storage'))]"
            ],
            "identity": {
                "type": "userAssigned",
                "userAssignedIdentities": {
                    "/subscriptions/<MySubscription>/resourcegroups/<MyResourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/<MyIdentityID>": {}
                }
            },
            "properties": {
                "forceUpdateTag": "[parameters('utcNow')]",
                "storageAccountSettings": {
                    "storageAccountName": "[variables('storage')]",
                    "storageAccountKey": "[listKeys(variables('storage'), '2019-04-01').keys[0].value]"
                },
                // "azPowerShellVersion": "3.0",
                "azCliVersion": "2.5.0",
                "scriptContent": "[concat('az storage blob service-properties update --account-name ', variables('storage'), ' --static-website --index-document index.html')]",
                "timeout": "PT2M",
                "cleanupPreference": "OnSuccess",
                "retentionInterval": "PT1H"
            }
        },
```

To do so, I created a new Managed Identity, and I affected **Contributor** role to this identity for my resource group. But during the creation of the **deploymentScripts** resource, it stays in 'Deploying' mode during a long time, and then failed with this error :

```
Exceeded maximum wait time of '00:05:00'. Message: 'First-party app identity has not become effective yet.'. (Code: DeploymentScriptOperationFailed)
```

I follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template?tabs=CLI#prerequisites) for getting the Identity ID so I'm pretty sure the **userAssignedIdentities** is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussions with a Software Engineer from Microsoft, it seems that I have to wait that the Managed Identity replicates to multiple servers internally on Azure so that my scripts can found the Identity to execute properly.

I created the Managed Identity manually, waited 1 day and after that the script ran properly.